# How to insert data into the same table and in same row when the user will enter the data into two different pages

Tags: php, mysql

I have two files: `register.php` and `register1.php`.

I also have one table: `users_details`.

The user will enter data first into the `register.php` file and then it will redirect the page to `regsiter1.php`. Now, here, I want that both the files data should be stored in one table and in same row.

Comment: show us , what u inserted from 2 pages & ur table Structure also.

Answer (score 0):

First file will insert/create row and second file will update that row with new data. you can use query string or session to keep current row id, second file will get that id and update that row. You can see query string and session examples on internet.

Answer (score -1):

Create the record once all the data has been collected. No need to create record in one page and then update database in another. Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` to retrieve the information from the first PHP page.